# Inequalities related to stability analysis

Tags: inequality, differential

I am doing a project on differential equations and stability analysis on economic models.

However I am stuck doing inequalities for the stability analysis. My source is [giving these conditions for the domain, underlined in red,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyafn.png) to be stable, and I am just not able to tell how these inequalities arise. The eigenvalues for the system are as follows

$$\rho_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^2-4}\right)$$

And the condition of stability for this system is $0>\rho_1>\rho_2$ as in the picture.

I have been trying for a long time to figure this out, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the systems of ODEs?

Comment: Of course - $\frac{d\pi}{dt}=\alpha * \pi - \sigma$ and $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}=\pi - \frac{1}{\beta}\sigma$